# Quickly mapping/modifying values in a large list of Python dicts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have some code that I'm trying to speed up.  Maybe what I've got is right, but whenever I ask on StackOverflow somebody usually knows a clever little trick "Use map!", "try this lambda", or "import iteratetools" and I'm hoping somebody can help here.  This is the section of code I'm concerned with:

```
#slowest part from here....
for row_dict in json_data:
    row_dict_clean = {}
    for key, value in row_dict.items():
        value_clean = get_cleantext(value)
        row_dict_clean[key] = value_clean
    json_data_clean.append(row_dict_clean)
    total += 1
#to here...
```

The concept is pretty simple.  I have a multi-million long `list` that contains dictionaries and I need to run each `value` through a little cleaner.  Then I end up with a nice list of cleaned dictionaries.  Any clever `iterate` tool that I'm not aware of that I should be using? Here is a more complete MVE to help play with it:

```
def get_json_data_clean(json_data):
    json_data_clean = []
    total = 0
    #slowest part from here....
    for row_dict in json_data:
        row_dict_clean = {}
        for key, value in row_dict.items():
            value_clean = get_cleantext(value)
            row_dict_clean[key] = value_clean
        json_data_clean.append(row_dict_clean)
        total += 1
    #to here...
    return json_data_clean

def get_cleantext(value):
    #do complex cleaning stuffs on the string, I can't change what this does
    value = value.replace("bad", "good")
    return value

json_data = [
    {"key1":"some bad",
     "key2":"bad things",
     "key3":"extra bad"},
    {"key1":"more bad stuff",
     "key2":"wow, so much bad",
     "key3":"who dis?"},
    # a few million more dictionaries
    {"key1":"so much bad stuff",
     "key2":"the bad",
     "key3":"the more bad"},
]

json_data_clean = get_json_data_clean(json_data)
print(json_data_clean)
```

Anytime I have nested for loops a little bell rings in my head, there is probably a better way to do this.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If the code still works then it might be more appropriate to migrate this to Code Review.

Comment: Ah, I totally forgot about that site.  My tea hasn't kicked in yet :)  Should I close this question and move it?

Comment: How about using filter()

Comment: oh, I hadn't thought of `filter()`

Comment: [A guide to code review for StackOverflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) is always worth reading -- CR might well be a better home, but the rules are a bit different there (can't have "stub code", for example)

Comment: One thing I would consider is whether you need to maintain ordering -- the work being done here looks nicely parallelizable, though that's easiest if the order of the data isn't important to maintain (and only relevant if you actually *have* a bunch of CPUs to split the task up into, and can prevent the split and reassemble tasks from becoming bottlenecks).

Comment: The order of the dictionaries will matter further down the code. :)  Good thought though.

Comment: (Personally, I'm not sure I'd pick Python for this at all -- CPU-bound tasks are not its strong point; see http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/url/julialang.org/benchmarks/benchmarks.ipynb, keeping in mind that the graph is in base-10 orders-of-magnitude on the Y axis).

Comment: Thank you all for the excellent ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must definitely ask clever guys at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but as a quick fix it appears you can just `map()` your transformation fucntion over a list of dictionaries as below:

```
def clean_text(value: str)-> str:
    # ...
    return value.replace("bad", "good")

def clean_dict(d: dict):
    return {k:clean_text(v) for k,v in d.items()}


json_data = [
    {"key1":"some bad",
     "key2":"bad things",
     "key3":"extra bad"},
    {"key1":"more bad stuff",
     "key2":"wow, so much bad",
     "key3":"who dis?"},
    # a few million more dictionaries
    {"key1":"so much bad stuff",
     "key2":"the bad",
     "key3":"the more bad"},
]

x = list(map(clean_dict, json_data))
```

A thing that gets left out is your `total` counter, but it never seems to leave the `get_json_data_clean()` anyways.

Not sure why @Daniel Gale proposed `filter()` as you are not throughing any values away, just transforming them.

Comment: Perfect, I'll play around with this.  This looks to do what I'm trying to do, squeeze a bit more speed out :)

Comment: I mixed them up, but was more importantly suggesting that using one of the methods filter/map/reduce would help when you are in a nested for loop problem. I agree map is the better of those methods to use in this case. I'm not sure how that affects performance but it makes the code cleaner. It may be that a list comprehension is faster. They would be worth comparing.